# Unusual JavaScript Addition Vs Concatenation behavior

Tags: javascript, concatenation, addition, arithmetic-expressions, integer-arithmetic

There are plenty of addition Vs concatenation questions on internet, but I'm not sure why I'm getting the behavior I am.  I'm not trying to "add" obvious strings and I've tried `parseInt` and `parseFloat` on all values to no avail.  I need to get the value from a `data-page` attribute which would contain a numeric value representation (I realize probably as an implicit string).  I notice so long as I am getting a value from the `data-page` attribute, I can't perform addition on the variables.  If I replace it with a hard-coded `1`, everything works fine.  The values should always be integers, but I tried `parseFloat` to see if I got the same behavior.  Which I did.

Some sample code is below. Assume `$("#pagination").attr('data-page').trim()` evaluates to `1`.

```
//Tried parseFloat
//datapage = 1  //This works as expected
dataPage = parseFloat($("#pagination").attr('data-page').trim()); //This does not work as expected
curPage = (parseFloat(dataPage) + parseFloat(1));
console.log(curPage); //Outputs '11' instead of '2'

//Tried parseInt
//datapage = 1  //This works as expected
dataPage = parseInt($("#pagination").attr('data-page').trim());
curPage = (parseInt(dataPage) + parseInt(1));
console.log(curPage); //Outputs '11' instead of '2'
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML as well? Both of your examples work just fine for me.

Comment: I think the code **without** the `parseFloat` and `parseInt` don't work. This should work, anyway why you call `parseFloat` and `parseInt` 2 times?

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini I call parseFloat/parseInt twice for redundancy to ensure I'm getting what I think I'm getting.  I wouldn't normally do that in production code.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is working as expected.  See this codepen:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBwOPW

HTML:

```
<body>
  <input id="pagination" data-page="1" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Your original JS unchanged.:

```
//Tried parseFloat
//datapage = 1  //This works as expected
dataPage = parseFloat($("#pagination").attr('data-page').trim()); //This does not work as expected
curPage = (parseFloat(dataPage) + parseFloat(1));
console.log(curPage); //Outputs '11' instead of '2'

//Tried parseInt
//datapage = 1  //This works as expected
dataPage = parseInt($("#pagination").attr('data-page').trim());
curPage = (parseInt(dataPage) + parseInt(1));
console.log(curPage); //Outputs '11' instead of '2'
```

Comment: You might want to revise this to use the "in-house" web snippet facility.

Answer (score 0):

After some of the comments and assurance the JavaScript was correct I started looking at other differences between my existing code and the example snippets posted.  Turns out the issue has to do with Smarty - the template engine I'm using.  The `data-page` attribute is populated with a Smarty variable and when I switched that out with a hard-coded value the addition worked as expected.

What doesn't work:

```
<div id="pagination" class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 paginationBar" data-page="{$paginationPage}" data-pageMax="{$paginationPageMax}" data-pageQty="{$paginationQty}">...<div>
```

What works:

```
<div id="pagination" class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 paginationBar" data-page="1" data-pageMax="1000" data-pageQty="10">...<div>
```

I'm not sure why this is posing an issue just yet.  But this definitely is what is causing it.  If I figure out why and/or how to correct it I'll be sure to update this answer.

Comment: What happens if you try something crazy like `10000-(9999-(dataPage))`? Mathematically, this should come out exactly the same as `dataPage+1`, but it doesn't use any plus signs.